# Android cookies for login in webview

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I have a specific url to load in web view, but it's redirecting me to the login page due to the cookies . The web login page uses the same username, password credential I use for my native login . So how can I set the cookies using the username, password I have so it won't redirect me to login page?

Currently I am sending the username, password with post data and after finishing I am loading the required url in another web view. But it's taking too long to load as it's loading to web view one after another.

```
 String postData = "username="+userName+"&password="+password;
```

webView.postUrl("logipage url", EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            webView2.loadUrl("Main URL");

        }
    });
```

Comment: What did you try? Show some code

Comment: edit your question with your code

Comment: You need to use  CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url, cookie);